# Why can file descriptors under UNIX be transmitted over sockets, but not over pipes?

Tags: sockets, unix, pipe, ipc, file-descriptor

I just learned about pipes and sockets today and that sockets are special because they allow you to transmit file descriptors between processes.

I've also looked up that it seems to be sendmsg() and the msghdr structure that are used to produce this behavior.

My professor told me that pipes can't be used to replicate this behavior/feature, but I am interested exactly what part of the implementation allows sockets to do what pipes can't.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a bit unfocused.  You seem to me to be asking why two different IO mechanisms have different semantics — they simply do.  Why is `st_size` not meaningful on a FIFO?

Comment: @pilcrow "'By means of a faculty,' he had said, or at least meant. But is that an answer? An explanation? Or is it not rather a repetition of the question?" (Nietzsche, Beyond Good and Evil, http://nietzsche.holtof.com/reader/friedrich-nietzsche/beyond-good-and-evil/aphorism-11-quote_46e23b59f.html)
"But answers like that belong in comedy, [...]" (same source as above). 


I do not know why st_size is not meaningful on a FIFO, please explain.